# update table in rshiny (using dttable) and save the new information into a variable

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a table where the user can change the data, and the updated data will be used for future calculations.
Here is an example of a table, and I want it so that when the table is modified, the necessary information on the main panel will be updated accordingly.
Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    DTOutput("mytable"),
    actionButton("update", "Update")
  ),
                mainPanel(
                  plotOutput("plot"),
                  verbatimTextOutput("text")
                  )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  tab <- reactiveValues(df = {data.frame(
    num = 1:5, 
    x = LETTERS[1:5],
    y = c(14,5,8,9,13)
  )})
  
  output$mytable <- renderDT({
    DT::datatable(tab$df, editable = T, selection = "none")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$update,{
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      tab$df %>% ggplot(aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
      
    })
    
    output$text <- renderPrint({
      tab$df$x
    })
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach with your `server` method.

First, add an `observeEvent` to detect edits/changes to your datatable. When there are, the changes are stored in your `tab` which is reactive.

Second, if you want an `actionbutton` to redo the plot and text, then would also make a second `reactiveValues` `rv` and `observeEvent` to store and update them when the button is pressed.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  tab <- reactiveValues(df = {data.frame(
    num = 1:5, 
    x = LETTERS[1:5],
    y = c(14,5,8,9,13)
  )})
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    plot = NULL,
    text = NULL
  )
  
  output$mytable <- renderDT({
    DT::datatable(tab$df, editable = T, selection = "none")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$mytable_cell_edit, {
    row <- input$mytable_cell_edit$row
    clmn <- input$mytable_cell_edit$col
    tab$df[row, clmn] <- input$mytable_cell_edit$value
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$update,{
    rv$text <- tab$df$x
    rv$plot <- tab$df %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
        geom_point()
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    rv$plot
  })
    
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    rv$text
  })
  
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working only when changing the numbers(y column). Why The changes in x column are reflected as NA?

Comment: Found the solution to my questions: I need to add the arguments stringsAsFactors = F when defining the dataframe